# Angular (6/7/8) - Show a spinner while waiting for the content from window.location.assign to load

Tags: angular, spinner

My app is in Angular 7+.  When user clicks on an external link, I use "window.location.assign" to redirect the page. The external page may take time to load.  Therefore, I need to display a spinner before the page is being loaded.  Can someone point me to an example or suggestion on how to achieve that? TIA.

Comment: Once window.location is invoked angular is out of the picture. You could load it to an iframe and wait for the load event then flip it to top but that's about it.

Answer (score 0):

If you change location that is loading new document that document (url) is in charge  off DOM. Maybe you can load page in iframe element. In that case you have control of  DOM and you can hide iframe and show spinner until loaded, maybe like answer in:
[load iframe with spinner](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34708261/load-iframe-with-spinner)